# Copying git repo from one partition to another and then link

Tags: windows, git, macos, partition

I have a LARGE git repo (over 10 GBs) that I simply cannot clone due to network performance. I have the repo on my Mac partition. I copy the folder over to the Windows partition using BootCamp. If I navigate into the folder on windows there are no .git files. So I create a new git entry. If I try and add a remote to the repo URL and pull, git tries to download all the files which would be redundant and would eventually time out.

How can I configure the copied repo so that I can begin pushing and pulling changes normally?

Comment: You need to copy the `.git` directory.

Comment: Any "normal" Git repository (in the absense of any weird hard-core configuration), consists of a work tree -- the place where you have your files checked out and edit them, and *the repository itself* -- which is located in the subdirectory named ".git" in the work tree. Unix-like systems (presumably, Mac OS X counts as one) have a policy according to which the filesystem entities whose names start with a single dot character are considered to be "hidden", and may hence not be shown by "dumb" tools like GUI file managers, and may be omitted from being copied.

Comment: …So you'd need to invent a way to verify that directory was copied, and/or force that "boot camp thing" to copy it. And while we're on it, I think *this* problem is for the ["Ask Different"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) (oh, my!) stackexchange site, not SO.